# En la sobrecarga de <<, dice que hay un error de inicializador antes del &

Tags: c++, poo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class vector {

    private: int *pv, tam;

    public: vector (int *a, int tam){
        pv= new int [tam];
        for (int i=0; i<tam; i++){
            pv[i]=a[i];
        }
    }
    vector operator + (vector b);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &o, vector b);
}

////
ostream & operator << (ostream &o, vector b){
    for (int i=o; int i<b.tam; i++){
    o<<b.pv[i]<<endl;
    return o;
    }
}
////
vector::operator + (vector b){
    int tamanio= this->tam+b.tam;
    vector aux(0,0);
    aux.pv= new int [tamanio];

    for (int i=0; i<this->tam; i++){
        aux.pv[i]=this->pv[i];
    }
    for (int j=this->tam; j<tamanio; j++){
        aux.pv[j]=b.pv[j];
    }
    aux.tam=tamanio;
    return aux;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int v1[3]; int v2[3];

    for (int i=0;i<3; i++){
        v1[i]=i++;
        v2[i]=i++;
    }
    vector v(v1, 3); vector vv(v2,3); vector res(v1,0);
    res=v+vv;
    cout<<res;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu código tiene los siguientes errores:

- En el constructor de vector no asigna el valor del atributo `tam`.
- Dentro de la implementación de ostream tú estas asignando el ostream a la variable `i` que sirve para iterar : `for (int i=o`.
- Usted esta retornado el ostream en la primera iteración del `for`, lo debes hacer despues de iterarlo completamente.
- En la expresión: `vector operator + (vector b);` estas indicando que debe retornar un nuevo objeto `vector` pero su implementación no lo hace: `vector::operator + (vector b){`, lo correcto es `vector vector::operator + (vector b){`.
- En las siguientes líneas: `for (int j=this->tam; j<tamanio; j++){ aux.pv[j]=b.pv[j]; ...` j inicia en la posición `this->tam` pero tu lo estas usando como indice en `b.pv[j]`, lo cual va a generar acceder a posición de memoria no reservada.
- No se debe modificar la variable que se usa para iterar en un loop for que se usa como indices en los arrays, en su caso hay estan las siguientes líneas: `v1[i]=i++;` `v2[i]=i++;`, *¿por qué es incorrecto?*, porque esta variando el indice, por ejemplo vemos el caso inicial: `v1[i]=i++;` i=0, `i++` es 1 y por lo tanto equivale a `v1[1] = 1`; y despues `v2[i] = i++`equivaldria a `v2[2] = 2;` y en la siguiente iteración `v1[4] = 4`, y ya estamos en terreno peligroso ya que no hemos reservado esa memoría.
- Si desea asignar un puntero nulo: `vector aux(0,0);` se recomienda usar `nullptr`.

Corrigiendo lo anterior obtenemos el siguiente código:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class vector {
    int *pv;
    int tam;
public:
    vector (int *a, int tam):
        pv(new int(tam)),
        tam(tam)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<tam; i++){
            pv[i]=a[i];
        }
    }
    vector operator + (const vector & b);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &o, const vector & b);
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &o, const vector & b){
    for (int i= 0; i< b.tam; i++){
        o << b.pv[i] << "\n";
    }
    return o;
}

vector vector::operator+(const vector & b){
    int tamanio = this->tam+b.tam;
    vector aux(nullptr, 0);
    aux.pv= new int[tamanio];
    for (int i=0; i<this->tam; i++){
        aux.pv[i]=this->pv[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j< b.tam; j++){
        aux.pv[j+this->tam] = b.pv[j];
    }
    aux.tam=tamanio;
    return aux;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int v1[3];
    int v2[3];

    for (int i=0;i<3; i++){
        v1[i]=i+1;
        v2[i]=i+2;
    }
    vector v(v1, 3);
    vector vv(v2, 3);
    vector res(v1, 0);
    res = v + vv;
    std::cout <<"v:\n";
    std::cout<< v;
    std::cout << "vv:\n";
    std::cout<< vv;
    std::cout << "res:\n";
    std::cout<< res;
    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
v:
1
2
3
vv:
2
3
4
res:
1
2
3
2
3
4
```